# How to build generic nuxt image accepting env variables during runtime and not buld time

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, environment

I have almost no experience with NUXT.JS so sorry if asking total stupid question. Anyway:
My task is to prepate workflow how to deploy NUXT app via Docker. I need to build generic image, that is build with sort of env variables reference only during build time, so when the image is used for container deployment on specific docker host via docker compose, I want to be able to change for instance Apollo or Axios Base URL inside docker compose file in environment section. in other words: Build generic image to be able to map specific configuration parameters inside nuxt.config.js during runtime with environment variables and not during BUILD TIME. Is there any chance how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: SO is not a tutorial platform. Also, some effort is required from your part.

Comment: It appears `runTimeConfig` behaves differently in production mode. The Nuxt docs are "light" on this. Docs claim `In production runtime, you should use platform environment variables and .env is not used.` however my attempts to use docker env vars at runtime are not recognized.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-runtime-config#using-the-env-file